# rxjs: withLatestFrom precedence

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've coded an `Observable` using `withLatestFrom`:

```
this.scopes$ = service.getScopes();
```

Also, I've coded this another `Observable`:

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
    @Input('app')
    public set app(app: ApplicationUser) {
        this._app = app;
        this.inputApp$.next({...this._app});
    };

    constructor(...) {
       this.inputApp$ = new BehaviorSubject<ApplicationUser>({...this._app});
       this.app$ = this.inputApp$.pipe(this.digestAppPipe());
    }
}
```

where `digestAppPipe` is:

```
private digestAppPipe = () => pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.scopes$, anySelectFunction,
    ...
);
```

So, `app$` is a combination of `inputApp$ + scopes$` observables.

The problem is that `inputApp$` emits before than `scopes$`, so the combination is never reached.

Any ideas about how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `combineLatest` utility function:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
this.app$ = combineLatest(this.inputApp$, this.scopes$).pipe(...);
```

`combineLatest` emits only after all of the observables have emitted value and then every time any of them emits.